# Nginx rule for redirecting all image files

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I am new to nginx. I want to redirect the fake image path of an website to original image path. For example assume that I have so many images on example.com home directory such as example.com/a.jpeg, example.com/b.png and example.com/c.jpg. If any one calls example.com/tests/a.jpeg, then it should redirect to example.com/a.jpeg.

So I want to write a rewrite rule for redirecting image files to original location.

Answer (score 1):

So an image file within any directory of the hierarchy should actually be found at the top of the document root. So the URI `/path/to/image.jpeg` is mapped to the physical location `$document_root/image.jpeg`.

This is easily achieved with a [regex location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) combined with [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

```
root /path/to/document/root;

location ~* ([^/]+\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg))$ {
    try_files /$1 =404;
}
```